# x86 UEFI Boot: Is the conventional 1MiB padding from address 0 really required for UEFI?

Tags: x86, boot, bios, uefi

I'm relatively new into kernel development and boot process on x86_64 with UEFI. A lot of general OS dev resources recommend to leave the first 1 MiB in the initial object file free/untouched, because there are "lot's of legacy functionalities I/O mapped, for example the VGA framebuffer".

Is this only true for legacy BIOS boot or still true for UEFI?

**Example linker script:**

```
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS {
    /* According to https://intermezzos.github.io/book/first-edition/hello-world.html
     * there is lots of memory mapped I/O and 1MiB is a conventional padding (legacy?!)
     * TODO find out if this only is valid for legacy BIOS boot or also for UEFI!
     */
    . = 1M;

    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }

     .bss :
    {
      *(COMMON)
      *(.bss)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory map provided by the EFI boot services function GetMemoryMap identifies all the pages that are used and those that are available. After calling ExitBootServices, you should feel free to use any available pages.

Prior to calling ExitBootServices, you should call AllocatePool or AllocatePages to obtain memory. You can call AllocatePages with type = ALLOCATE_MAX_ADDRESS and address = 0xfffff if you specifically want to allocate memory within the first megabyte.